# Fine-tuning a pre-trained VGG16 model on my own data using TF-Slim

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, classification, conv-neural-network, tf-slim

I am trying to fine-tune the VGG-16 pretrained model using TF-Slim however, i am having trouble at the beginning (when attempting to preprocess the data i.e converting images from tiff to jpeg and then to tfrecord format).

Could anyone advise on the best method to use in order to finetune the model to suit these images?

Or maybe point me in the direction of a step by step guide on how to do this? Apologies as i am new to convnets and i am trying to figure out how to begin fine-tuning.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the detailed steps on how to fine-tuning a pre-trained model in the below TF slim walkthrough on flower dataset
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/slim_walkthrough.ipynb

Also, I would recommend you to look into the below git for implementing on a custom dataset. 
https://gist.github.com/omoindrot/dedc857cdc0e680dfb1be99762990c9c/

Comment: While this link might provide some limited, immediate help, an answer [should include sufficient context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, to make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. In addition, other users tend to respond negatively to answers which are [barely more than a link to an external site](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370), and they [might be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).